# Free abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Is the following implication true? If this is the case, how can this be shown?

If $G$ is a one-relator (neither power nor commutator relation), two-generator group, then $G/G'$ (where $G'$ is commutator subgroup) is not free abelian of rank 2.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends what you call a commutator relation. For a free group $F$ of rank 2 and $w \in F$, $F/\langle w^F\rangle$ is free abelian of rank 2 if and only if $w \in F'$.

Comment: Really you need the exponent sums on this relator to be $0$, so for example the relation $ab^{-2}a^2ba^{-3}b$ works fine.

Comment: @SteveD Thanks. Do you mean it only works if the relation exponent sum is zero?

Comment: @DerekHolt Well, good question. I am not quiet sure about this either. Have you got a good reference, where I can read about these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me make this into an answer. Any 2-generator 1-relator group has the form $G = \langle a,b \mid w \rangle = F/\langle w^F \rangle$ for some $1 \ne w \in F$,
where $F$ is the free group with generators $a,b$.

So $G/G' \cong F/N$ with $N = F'\langle w^F \rangle$. Since $F/F'$ is free abelian of rank 2, and no proper quotient of $F/F'$ is free abelian of rank 2, $G/G'$ is free abelian of rank 2 if and only if $w \in F'$.

As SteveD pointed out, the condition $w \in F'$ is equivalent to the exponent sums of $a$ and $b$ in $w$ both being $0$. You can see that as follows. Any element of $F'$ is a product of commutators, so it has this property. Conversely, if $w$ has exponent sums of $a$ and $b$ both $0$ then, since $F/F'$ is commutative, the image of $w$ in $F/F'$ is trivial and hence $w \in F'$.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't totally get it. So if $w$ is not a commutator relation, i.e. $w \notin F'$, then G is not free abelian of rank 2 and so $G/G'$? If $G$ is not free abelian of rank 2 so $G/G'$?!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write that $G/G'$ is free abelian of rank 2 if and only if $w \in F'$. I've corrected it now.